# The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.5.1 on newest version

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, gradle

I have seen a lot of posts on this issue and the answers were all "upgrade your Kotlin version". The problem is that I am already using the latest versions of Kotlin (for now) and the error / warning still appears when I use `>flutter run --release`.

**android/build.gradle**:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

**gradle-wrapper.properties**

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-all.zip
```

**Release Log**:

```
> flutter run --release
Launching lib\main.dart on SM G990B in release mode...
e: <user_files>/myApp/build/better_player/.transforms/37fbb17d8aa9e4563e70c2fce29a3240/transformed/out/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF
/better_player_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is
1.5.1.
e: <user_files>/myApp/build/wakelock/.transforms/ff661fedb16e56513c66400978568e0d/transformed/out/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/wake
lock_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.5.1.
e: <user_files>/myApp/build/package_info_plus/.transforms/16efc48fb788cfa9881facf70e028d76/transformed/out/jars/classes.jar!/META
-INF/package_info_plus_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected ver
sion is 1.5.1.
e: <user_files>/myApp/build/workmanager/.transforms/d96e0ff60c09a3780329e98266bf5470/transformed/out/jars/classes.jar!/META-INF/w
orkmanager_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.5.
1.
e: <user_files>/myApp/build/flutter_image_compress/.transforms/7fd7cbac29954654e675e8bdd94e5277/transformed/out/jars/classes.jar!
/META-INF/flutter_image_compress_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, ex
pected version is 1.5.1.
e: <user_files>/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.7.10/d70d7d2c56371f7aa18f32e984e3e2e998fe9081/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.
7.10.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expec
ted version is 1.5.1.
e: <user_files>/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7/1.7.10/1ef73fee66f45d52c67e2aca12fd945dbe0659bf/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.
7.10.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expec
ted version is 1.5.1.
e: <user_files>/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/androidx.annotation/annotation/1.5.0/857678d6b4ca7b28571ef7935c668bdb57e15027/annotation-1.5.0.jar!/META-INF/
annotation.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.5.1.
e: <user_files>/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.7.10/d2abf9e77736acc4450dc4a3f707fa2c10f5099d/kotlin-stdlib-1.7.10.jar!/
META-INF/kotlin-stdlib.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is
1.5.1.
e: <user_files>/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-common/1.7.10/bac80c520d0a9e3f3673bc2658c6ed02ef45a76a/kotlin-stdlib-commo
n-1.7.10.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-common.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1,
 expected version is 1.5.1.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by upgrading Flutter version

> `flutter upgrade`

(The error logs aren't that explicit on this issue ?)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing kotlin version to `1.5.1`

```
    buildscript {
        ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.1'
        repositories {
            google()
            mavenCentral()
        }
    
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.3'
            classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        }
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't work:

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.5.1/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.5.1.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.5.1/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.5.1.pom
     Required by:
         project :